# Can you change the color of a textview in a recyclerview adapter after a certain condition is met in Main Activity?

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have a basic function that displays the elapsed time every time the button is pressed. I cannot get the logic in MainActivity to transfer to the recyclerview adapter. I simply want the text output color to change to red after the time passes 5 seconds. I have tried to research how to do this for the past week and I cannot find the exact answer.  I'm hoping someone can help.

I have tried it with and without the boolean in the data class.  I wasn't sure if that was required.

Here is my code:

**Main Activity:`**

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    var startTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()
    var displaySeconds = 0

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private val secondsList = generateSecondsList()
    private val secondsAdapter = Adapter(secondsList)

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        recyclerView.adapter = secondsAdapter
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false)

        binding.button.setOnClickListener {
            getDuration()
            addSecondsToRecyclerView()
        }

    }

    fun getDuration(): Int {
        val endTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()
        val elapsedMilliSeconds: Long = endTime - startTime
        val elapsedSeconds = elapsedMilliSeconds / 1000.0
        displaySeconds = elapsedSeconds.toInt()
        return displaySeconds
    }

    private fun generateSecondsList(): ArrayList<Seconds> {
        return ArrayList()
    }

    fun addSecondsToRecyclerView() {
        val addSeconds =
            Seconds(getDuration(), true)
        secondsList.add(addSeconds)
        secondsAdapter.notifyItemInserted(secondsList.size - 1)
    }
}
```

**Adapter:**

```kotlin
var adapterSeconds = MainActivity().getDuration()

class Adapter(
    private val rvDisplay: MutableList<Seconds>
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.AdapterViewHolder>() {

        class AdapterViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        val textView1: TextView = itemView.tv_seconds
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): AdapterViewHolder {
        val myItemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(
            R.layout.rv_item,
            parent, false
        )
        return AdapterViewHolder(myItemView)
    }


    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: Adapter.AdapterViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentDisplay = rvDisplay[position]

        currentDisplay.isRed = adapterSeconds > 5

        holder.itemView.apply {
            val redColor = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.red).toString()
            val blackColor = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.black).toString()
            if (currentDisplay.isRed) {
                holder.textView1.setTextColor(redColor.toInt())
                holder.textView1.text = currentDisplay.rvSeconds.toString()
            } else {
                holder.textView1.setTextColor(blackColor.toInt())
                holder.textView1.text = currentDisplay.rvSeconds.toString()
            }
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = rvDisplay.size
}
```

**Data Class:**

```kotlin
data class Seconds(
    var rvSeconds: Int,
    var isRed: Boolean
)
```

Answer (score 0):

when you call `secondsList.add(addSeconds)` then the data that is already inside `secondsList` should be updated too.

you could do something like

```kotlin
    private var secondsList = generateSecondsList() // make this var

    fun addSecondsToRecyclerView() {
        val addSeconds =
            Seconds(getDuration(), true)
        secondsList.add(addSeconds)
        if ( /* TODO check if time has passed */) {
           secondsList = secondsList.map { it.isRed = true }
           secondsAdapter.rvDisplay = secondsList // TODO also make rvDisplay a var
           secondsAdapter.notifyDatasetChanged() // also need to tell rv to redraw the all views
        } else {
           secondsAdapter.notifyItemInserted(secondsList.size - 1)
        }
    }
```

that might work, but to be honest it looks bad... There is already a lot of logic inside Activity. Read about MVVM architecture and LiveData, there should be another class called ViewModel that would keep track of time and the data. Activity should be as simple as possible, because it has lifecycle, so if you rotate the screen, all your state will be lost.

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn't really working because of this:

```
var adapterSeconds = MainActivity().getDuration()

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: Adapter.AdapterViewHolder, position: Int) {
    ...
    currentDisplay.isRed = adapterSeconds > 5
    ...
}
```

You're only setting `adapterSeconds` right there, so it never updates as time passes. I assume you want to know the moment 5 seconds has elapsed, and then update the `RecyclerView` at that moment - in that case you'll need some kind of timer task that will fire after 5 seconds, and can tell the adapter to display things as red. Let's deal with that first:

```
class Adapter( private val rvDisplay: MutableList ) : RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.AdapterViewHolder>() {

    private var displayRed = false
        set(value) {
            field = value
            // Refresh the display - the ItemChanged methods mean something about the items
            // has changed, rather than a structural change in the list
            // But you can use notifyDataSetChanged if you want (better to be specific though)
            notifyItemRangeChanged(0, itemCount)
        }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: Adapter.AdapterViewHolder, position: Int) {
        if (displayRed) {
            // show things as red - you shouldn't need to store that state in the items
            // themselves, it's not about them - it's an overall display state, right?
        } else {
            // display as not red
        }
    }
```

So with that setter function, every time you update `displayRed` it'll refresh the display, which calls `onBindViewHolder`, which checks `displayRed` to see how to style things. It's better to put all this internal refreshing stuff inside the adapter - just pass it data and events, let it worry about what needs to happen internally and to the `RecyclerView` it's managing, y'know?

---

Now we have a thing we can set to control how the list looks, you just need a timer to change it. Lots of ways to do this - a `CountdownTimer`, a coroutine, but let's keep things simple for this example and just `post` a task to the thread's `Looper`. We can do that through any `View` instead of creating a `Handler`:

```
// in MainActivity
recyclerView.postDelayed({ secondsAdapter.displayRed = true }, 5000)
```

That's it! Using any view, post a delayed function that tells the adapter to display as red.

It might be more helpful to store that runnable as an object:

```
private val showRedTask = Runnable { secondsAdapter.displayRed = true }
...
recyclerView.postDelayed(showRedTask, 5000)
```

because then you can easily [cancel it](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler#removeCallbacks(java.lang.Runnable))

```
recyclerView.removeCallbacks(showRedTask)
```

Hopefully that's enough for you to put some logic together to get what you want. Set `displayRed = false` to reset the styling, use `removeCallbacks` to cancel any running task, and `postDelayed` to start a new countdown. Not the only way to do it, but it's pretty neat!

Comment: That was really cool, but not quite exactly what I was going for.  I may have not asked my question correctly. If I press the button and it has been under 5 seconds, I want those seconds to be displayed in black.  Any seconds displayed AFTER 5 seconds I wish to show in red.  Is there a simple way to accomplish that?  I understand this is a crude project, but it is helping me understand some of the fundamentals.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out using a companion object in Main Activity with a boolean set to false.  If the time exceeded 5 seconds, then it set to true.

The adapter was able to recognize the companion object and change the color of seconds to red if they exceeded 5.